# Extract value after the last number in a string

Tags: sql, oracle

HAVE

M1234TESTABC

M34567TESTABC

M100023459ABC

M234TEST

WANT

TESTABC

TESTABC

ABC

TEST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '\D+$') as last_part
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name(value) AS
SELECT 'M1234TESTABC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'M34567TESTABC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'M100023459ABC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'M234TEST' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| LAST_PART |
| --- |
| TESTABC |
| TESTABC |
| ABC |
| TEST |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NR15li7M)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regex replacement approach here:

```sql
SELECT col, REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '.*[0-9]', '') AS col_out
FROM yourTable;
```

This approach behaves correctly should the input have no numbers at all, in which case the original value would be returned.

Comment: The last argument (`''`) is redundant, isn't it?